# Touchpad recognized as generic ps/2 mouse on a Dell Inspiron 13z 5323

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, 13.04, multi-touch, input-devices

After installing Ubuntu my touchpad has basic functionality but no edge scrolling, multitouch, or any advanced features.  Xinput list shows it as a generic ps/2 mouse:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

There must be a way to change it to recognizing it as a touchpad, but I'm pretty new to ubuntu and linux.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 13z 5323.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution in this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102346